# Is there any significance in the cry "Euan, euan, eu-oi-oi-oi" in Prince Caspian?

Tags: c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia, allusions

In *Prince Caspian*, there's a passage where Aslan apparently uses his power to summon up the spirit of Old Narnia, leading to the eventual defeat of the Telmarines with very little bloodshed. A wild party ensues, featuring [Bacchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysus), [Silenus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silenus), a lot of girls, and a lot of vines and grapes. This nod to ancient paganism within the Christian allegory of the Narnia series are the subject of a [whole other question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18318/17), but here I'm asking specifically about their call, seen as follows (emphasis mine):

> She never saw where certain other people came from who were soon capering about among the trees. One was a youth, dressed only in a fawn-skin, with vine-leaves wreathed in his curly hair. His face would have been almost too pretty for a boy’s, if it had not looked so extremely wild. You felt, as Edmund said when he saw him a few days later, “There’s a chap who might do anything—absolutely anything.” He seemed to have a great many names—Bromios, Bassareus, and the Ram were three of them. There were a lot of girls with him, as wild as he. There was even, unexpectedly, someone on a donkey. And everybody was laughing: and **everybody was shouting out, “Euan, euan, eu-oi-oi-oi.”**

I've tried to Google this phrase but found only references to this very passage in the Narnia books. **Does it have any significance in terms of the mythology of Bacchus and Silenus?** Lewis seems to have taken care over the writing of this passage, including a lot of hints for the educated reader on who these people are (Bromios and Bassareus are old names for Bacchus/Dionysus) before Susan and Lucy come right out and say it. So I wonder if their cry, repeated again a few paragraphs later, is also a reference to something. To me it looks both Greek, with all those vowels, and reminiscent of the traditional British ["Oggy, oggy, oggy, oi-oi-oi"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oggy_Oggy_Oggy).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently ’euoi’ is a ‘cry of impassioned rapture in ancient Bacchic revels’, per [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euoi) and ‘Euan’ or ‘Euhan’ is a Latin name for Bacchus, per [Notre Dame University](http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/lookup.pl?stem=euan).

Comment: Well well. I think I've never seen (on this site) such a short answer which solves the question so perfectly. Don't even know if there's anything more to add here.